# Laravel unexpected error "class user contains 3 abstract methods..."

Tags: php, laravel

While programming my Authentication app on Laravel, I came across to an error I've never seen before. I've been brainstorming for almost an hour for the cause of this problem but yet I can't find a solution.

Error:

> Class User contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::setRememberToken, Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberTokenName)

User.php Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

protected $fillable = [
    "email",
    "username",
    "password",
    "password_temp",
    "code",
    "active",
    "created_at",
    "updated_at",
    "banned"
];

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

}
```

And the RegisterController.php

```
<?php

class RegisterController extends BaseController {

public function getRegister()
{
    return View::make('template.home.register');
}

public function postRegister()
{
    $rules = [
        "email"         => "required|email|max:50|unique:users",
        "username"      => "required|max:50|min:5|unique:users",
        "password"      => "required|max:50|min:6",
        "password_again"=> "required|same:password",
    ];

    $messages = ["required" => "This field is required." ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        $email      = Input::get('email');
        $username   = Input::get('username');
        $password   = Input::get('password');
        $code       = str_random(60);

        $user = User::create([
            'email'         => $email,
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => Hash::make($password),
            'code'          => $code,
            'activated'     => 0,
            'banned'        => 0
        ]);

        if ($user)
        {
            Mail::send('template.email.activate', ['link' => URL::route('activate', $code), 'username' => $username], function($message) use ($user)
            {
                $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Account Registration');
            });

            return Redirect::route('register')->with('homeError', 'There was a problem creating your account.');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::route('register')->with('homeError', 'Account could not be created.');
}
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Check `RemindableInterface.php` and `UserInterface.php` to be sure that you've accounted for all the methods in your class.  They should all be there as it is, unless you've modified them at all.

Comment: Just checked laravel.com.  Follow these directions for upgrade instructions http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26

Comment: @user3158900 This should be an answer because it will definitely solve the problem. Don't forget to add a short summary of the solution in addition to the link.

Comment: @Sam As far as I can remember, I have the latest Composer version as so, the latest laravel 4 installtion.

Comment: @user2672192 It's funny that you added the names of the missing functions by edit. You would've had an answer immediately with these function names in your question :P

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Ah found it.

Its apparently documented Laravel Update.

You can check Laravel docs to fix your issues:

"First, add a new, nullable remember_token of VARCHAR(100), TEXT, or equivalent to your users table.

Next, if you are using the Eloquent authentication driver, update your User class with the following three methods:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

"

See http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade for further details.

Comment: If you were to have a `UserSeeder` with the remember_token, it would now invalidate all sessions and everyone would have to login again?

Comment: Anybody knows why this doesn't work in a namespaced class. It works in the class without a namespace.

Comment: @SimonKjellberg When we're updating the Laravel framework, we should identify our exact version, then go to http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade  and follow the changes in every update from our version to the latest. After that, we run composer update. I was on 4.1.25, so I had to check the changes for 3 update steps. Only had to change this little thing (in this answer), which took me 2 minutes. I think this is way better than have the Laravel guys implement ugly patches and workarounds just to not break the thing.

Comment: @PedroMoreira When you have multiple projects with a lot of dependencies, checking the changelog for every update becomes impossible. That's why standards like semver (http://semver.org/) exist so you can safely assume that a patch release will only fix bugs and not introduce any breaking changes. I'm not sure why you're even mentioning "ugly patches and workarounds" when it's simply a question about the versioning convention.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a pro at implementing [PHP Interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), but I believe you need to include all methods of `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` in your `User` class (since it implements them).  Otherwise, the class is ["abstract"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and must be defined as such.

By my knowledge, a PHP interface is a set of guidelines that a class must follow.  For instance, you can have a general interface for a specific database table.  It would include definition of methods like `getRow()`, `insertRow()`, `deleteRow()`, `updateColumn()`, etc.  Then you can use this interface to make multiple different classes for different database types (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Redis), but they must all follow the rules of the interface.  This makes migration easier, since you know no matter which database driver you are using to retrieve data from a table it will always implement the same methods defined in your interface (in other words, abstracting the database-specific logic from the class).

3 possible fixes, as far as I know:

```
abstract class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
}

class User extends Eloquent
{
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
     // include all methods from UserInterFace and RemindableInterface
}
```

I think #2 is best for you, since if your class doesn't implement all methods from `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` why would you need to say it does.

Comment: You're correct but he implements them all as far as I can see... At least if he uses the current Laravel version.

Comment: Hm, just got the same issues after pulling project that works(locally) from repo to server and doing fresh composer update.

Answer (score 2):

This is an update problem. Laravel force us to update the User.php model with the following code to fix this problem.

> Note: All existing "remember me" sessions will be invalidated by this
>   change, so all users will be forced to re-authenticate with your
>   application.

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;   
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
} 

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by adding `UserTrait` to `User.php`. Get the original `User.php` file [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php).
If you don't need the `rememberMe` stuff, you just need this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    use UserTrait;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

"First, add a new, nullable remember_token of VARCHAR(100), TEXT, or equivalent to your users table. which is put like this `$table->text('remember_token', 100)->nullable();` into the table then php artisan migrate. and update to your Elq model too.

Answer (score 0):

Class User contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

(Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthIdentifier,

Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthPassword,

Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, 
...)

Answer (score 0):

Class User contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

```
(Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthIdentifier, 
 Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthPassword, 
 Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, 
 ...
)
```

**Solution:** You add this code in User class (it's working for me)

```
use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
```

<sup>Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I also get this error.then i added:

```
getRememberToken()
setRememberToken($value)
getRememberTokenName()
```

here after code is working