# Sentry for Laravel error

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with a remote partner to develop a Laravel project.

I didn't have mcrypt installed, so I was referencing php by alias every time I need to use composer:

```
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php'
```

This was an alright fix until my remote friend installed the Sentry package, which I was unable to do.

Using another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)
I was able to reference the correct version of php with mcrpyt, update composer and install sentry.

Here is my problem:

Sentry works on my partner's local host and I it worked when I cloned his branch into a test file.   However, when I pull from the same branch into my local host, sentry does not work.

The error I receive is:

```
Class User contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or 
implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberToken, 
Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::setRememberToken,
Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getRememberTokenName)
```

So, my question is:  What is different between the clone and the pull that is making this bundle not work?  I am pretty sure that this is related to composer, even though I auto-dumped and updated it after I pulled the remote files.

I apologize if I haven't provided enough information to help diagnose the problem.  I will gladly provide more, but at the moment I am not sure what additional info would be helpful.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you and your partner are on different versions of Laravel, and there were some changes in [`v4.1.26`](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade).  You can either fix these upgrades, or be more specific in your `composer.json`.

For instance, try changing:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
```

To:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.1.25"
```

Either that, or you will have to make the necessary upgrade links documented in my [previous link](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) and seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23095058/703229).

Comment: you made that really easy. I was thinking this was going to be a complicated fix.  Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  It may be worth reading my answer on [why you should be specific with Composer versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23142151/703229) :)